# How can I solve "Object of class CI_Table could not be converted to string"?

Tags: php, codeigniter, libraries

I am new in CI, I follow a tutorial from website then I've got this error. Here's  my view code:

```
$data = array('table_open' => '<table class = "table-bordered">');

echo $this->table->set_template($data);

$col1 = array('data' => 'No');
$col2 = array('class' => 'col-md-4', 'data' => 'Agenda');
$col3 = array('class' => 'col-md-2', 'data' => 'Category');
$col4 = array('class' => 'col-md-2', 'data' => 'Date');
$option = array('class' => 'col-md-4', 'data' => 'Option');

echo $this->table->set_heading($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4, $option);
// echo $this->table->set_heading('No', 'Agenda', 'Category', 'Date', 'Option');
$no = 1;
if($agenda > 0) {
    foreach($agenda as $ag) {

        $item = $this->table->add_row($no++, $ag->agenda, $ag->agenda_cat, $ag->due_date,
                anchor('agenda/edit' . $ag->id_agenda, 'Edit', array('class' => 'btn btn-info col-md-offset-1')) . " " .
                anchor('agenda/delete' . $ag->id_agenda, 'Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger'))
            );
    }
    echo $item;
}

echo $this->table->generate();
```

Errors always occur for `table->set_heading()` and `table->add_rows()`.

And for the code echo `$this->table->set_template($data);` it's always give '1' as an output. Is anyone can help?

Comment: any lines indicating ??

Comment: Where is your $agenda array? What are the elements of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Answer:**

Remove all `echo` except `echo $this->table->generate();` this line.

**Error Reasons:**

`set_template` function returns true or false. if you echo this it will display 1 as it is returning true.

Remove `echo` from this line `echo $this->table->set_heading($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4, $option);` It will display that error message.

`set_heading` function returns object.You cannot echo object. remove `echo` or try to `print_r` or `var_dump` on that function.

For same reason you cannot use `echo $item;`

`add_row` function returns object and you assigning it to $item and You cannot echo object.

Answer (score 2):

Load the library in your Controller

```
$this->load->library('table');
```

or `Config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('table');
```

`set_heading` function always  returns object.So no use of `echo`

So Your Code(Remove `echo`)

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        'table_open' => '<table class="table-bordered">');

     $this->table->set_template($data);

    $col1 = array('data' => 'No');
    $col2 = array('class' => 'col-md-4', 'data' => 'Agenda');
    $col3 = array('class' => 'col-md-2', 'data' => 'Category');
    $col4 = array('class' => 'col-md-2', 'data' => 'Date');
    $option = array('class' => 'col-md-4', 'data' => 'Option');

    $this->table->set_heading($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4, $option);
    // echo $this->table->set_heading('No', 'Agenda', 'Category', 'Date', 'Option');
    $no = 0;

    if(empty($agenda))
    {
        foreach($agenda as $ag)
        {
            $this->table->add_row($no++, $ag['agenda'], $ag['agenda_cat'], $ag['due_date'],
                anchor('agenda/edit' . $ag['id_agenda'], 'Edit', array('class' => 'btn btn-info col-md-offset-1')) . " " .
                anchor('agenda/delete' . $ag['id_agenda'], 'Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')));
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
```

[codeigniter table](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html)

Comment: @Abdulla your answer is also correct.OP cannot up-vote due to reputation.but You got from me.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Respect you for such a great help. :)

Comment: Oh, I thought I can accept more than 1 answer ._.
I upvote your answer too

Comment: RizqiC @ShaifulIslam answer is point you well. keep accept that. :)